# how to specify a specific URL to be cached while using angular service worker?

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

- @angular/cli: 6.1.5
- @angular/pwa: 0.8.9

I am trying to cache a few specific API requests in my app using angular service worker. Following is a part of my "ngsw-config.json":

```
"dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/partone/parttwo/partthree"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "1h"
      }
    }
]
```

I have specified only one URL: *"/partone/parttwo/partthree"* but when I check my cache storage, it has entries for not only *"/partone/parttwo/partthree"* but for also for URLs like: *"/partone/parttwo/partthree-extrapath"*. How can I only have entries for paths which is just *"/partone/parttwo/partthree"*?

Comment: try sort of "/partone/parttwo/partthree!/**/*.*" https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#matching-navigation-request-urls or you could try with "urls": [
 "!/**/*.*", 
    "/partone/parttwo/partthree"
 ],

Comment: @Whisher: This is now not storing even `"/partone/parttwo/partthree"`. I am looking through the doc link you have provided, It may be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Whisher: I believe the provided link doesn't talk about API urls but rather browser's navigation urls.